# Warnings from makedepend

Tags: c, makefile

I'm using makedepend version 1.0.4 and despite using the Y option (which prevents searching of standard include directories) I get a warning:

```
$ cat test.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    return 0;
}
$ makedepend -Y test.c
makedepend: warning:  test.c, line 1: cannot find include file "stdio.h"
```

Any clues?

Comment: you might be interested in gcc with the -MM option.

Comment: @doron Thanks, but I prefer makedepend as I don't want to depend on a specific compiler (GCC).

Answer (score 0):

You have to download and rebuild makedepend with the UNIXOS flag enabled.

Details here: https://www.libreoffice.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=10021